# Elseif в echo

Tags: echo

Здраствуйте.
Возможно ли elsif в echo() выводить?
Знаю чо только if и else возможно.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Тернарный оператор?

```
$a = 1;
echo ($a == 1 ? 'One' : ($a == 5 ? 'Five' : ($a == 10 ? 'Ten' : 'Another number')));
// One
$a = 5;
echo ($a == 1 ? 'One' : ($a == 5 ? 'Five' : ($a == 10 ? 'Ten' : 'Another number')));
// Five
$a = 10;
echo ($a == 1 ? 'One' : ($a == 5 ? 'Five' : ($a == 10 ? 'Ten' : 'Another number')));
// Ten
$a = 100500;
echo ($a == 1 ? 'One' : ($a == 5 ? 'Five' : ($a == 10 ? 'Ten' : 'Another number')));
// Another number
```

P.S. Перед тем, как использовать такую конструкцию, советую пробежаться [по этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114899/).